# Eclipse Maven Dependency - weaveDependency issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to maven but not to java or Eclipse. I imported an existing maven project into Eclipse and I am having trouble with one of the dependencies. it is listed in POM.xml with groupid of net.bootstrap.api , version 2.0.1 
but maven can't find it on the central repository. it is a  weaveDependency. if I change groupid to org.webjars, bootstrap can be found with a different version, downloaded, and listed in Maven Dependencies, but it won't resolve as an import. Can someone tell me how I might get this issue resolved? The POM XML snippets:

```
 `<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
          <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
          <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <weaveDependencies>
            <weaveDependency>
              <groupId>net.bootstrap.api</groupId>
              <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>`
```

```
<properties>
<dagger.version>2.11</dagger.version>
<build.version>1.0.0</build.version>
<bootstrap.version>2.0.1</bootstrap.version>
```

The error I receive when I build with clean install, is "**Failure to find net.bootstrap.api:bootstrap:jar:2.0.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2**

I tried getting bootstrap from org.webjars (which does not have version 2.0.1) and changing the imports, but the imports won't resolve. I think I need to understand how weaveDependencies work since all the other Maven Dependencies are downloaded and the imports are resolved--this bootstrap is now the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open-source project from a vendor and I just discovered that others are having the same issue and is due to missing (propriertary) files. so this is not something anyone else can answer, I need to acquire the source files from the vendor.